# Orchard cms - custom login module with users in another database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, orchardcms, custom-membershipprovider

Im evaluating orchard cms for my employer and just wanted to ask a question about login and membership.

Our users and their roles are in another database which are exposed via an API and i would need to just get pointed in the right direction if it is possible to solve this in orchard.

The users must be able to login on the orchard site and it will display different content depending on their role. The admins and editors will use the built in user db.

What would be the correct way to solve this? Some kind of module or custom membership provider?

Also, is it possible to set visibility rules in orchard admin for content based on the roles from the other external DB?

Please do ask if you find something in my question confusing.

Comment: You have to replace the default membership implementation. As with most Orchard questions, scan the gallery for existing modules solving the same problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. So it is possible to do the things i mentioned above?  I am just worried i will hit a wall of limitations later on.

Comment: ok, i have searched the Orchard Module Gallery for something Membership related and unfortunately i cannot find a single module that would help. It is most likely because of the lack of knowledge, so any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Search?packageType=Modules&searchTerm=authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were not that many modules in the orchard gallery but have been playing around with a few so i am now answering my question and hope it helps others looking to build their own custom login.

The one which helped me most was the windows authentication module which was really easy to rewrite to work against an external service.

edit: typo